# ping other machines in my LAN to windows 2012 r2 host - KVM ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, guest

Yesterday i create windows 2012r2 VM in my ubuntu 16.04 server using KVM. Now i can ping between guest and host and in vice versa. But other system in my LAN not 
able to ping with the vm (i assign a static ip to my vm).

i used the below anser for forward the port, Alter the iptable rules. Also disable the windows firewall settings

Enable the fort forwarding in ubuntu host. But no progress Other machines will not ping to the VM.

*

```
root@server2:~# virsh net-dumpxml default
<network>
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>95e24458-3946-42cf-b013-71637b906842</uuid>
  <forward mode='nat'>
    <nat>
      <port start='1024' end='65535'/>
    </nat>
  </forward>
  <bridge name='virbr0' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='52:54:00:fd:24:95'/>
  <ip address='192.168.122.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.168.122.2' end='192.168.122.254'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

*

> root@server2:~# iptables -L Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT) target
>   prot opt source               destination ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere
>   anywhere             udp dpt:domain ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere
>   anywhere             tcp dpt:domain ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere
>   anywhere             udp dpt:bootps ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere
>   anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps
>
> Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source
>   destination ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.122.0/24 
>   ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.122.0/24
>   anywhere ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere REJECT
>   all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with
>   icmp-port-unreachable REJECT     all  --  anywhere
>   anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable ACCEPT     all 
>   --  anywhere             192.168.122.0/24     state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere
>   anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED ACCEPT     all  -- 
>   anywhere             anywhere ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere
>   192.168.122.196      tcp dpt:ssh state NEW DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
>
> Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source
>   destination ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere
>   udp dpt:bootpc
>
> root@server2:~#

Any mistake please advice.
I am new to this enviorment .Any one please help.

Answer (score 1):

I have same question some time i found this post helpful.

[Forwarding ports to guests in libvirt / KVM](https://serverfault.com/questions/170079/forwarding-ports-to-guests-in-libvirt-kvm)

Hope it will help you.

Comment: As a new bie i have some doubts .     Port 80 is used as the guest port and port 22 is used as the host's port ..?

Comment: All things are set well. but not able to ping from other systems in my lan to the windows 2012 r2 Vm in kvm.  I disabled the firewall on the windows , No progress,    While ping from other systems it will not shows any "host un reacheable" or time out error. I am stuck on it. No idea for what to do.

Comment: hi just make an edit please look into the question.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though you want the VM to be directly on the network rather than behind NAT?

In that case, [create a new network that bridges](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Networking) your KVM host's network interface and attach the VM there.